# con.getInputStream() throw exception in Android project, how to fix?

Tags: java, android

con.getInputStream() throw exception, when the code running on android,
but when copy the code to regular java project it is working,
The thrown object e contain "detailMessage = Permission denied".
my code::

```
            public static HttpData get(String sUrl) {
                HttpData ret = new HttpData();
                String str;
                StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
                try {
                        URL url = new URL(sUrl);
                        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                                buff.append(str);
                        }
                        ret.content = buff.toString();

                        //get headers
                        Map<String, List<String>> headers = con.getHeaderFields();
                        Set<Entry<String, List<String>>> hKeys = headers.entrySet();
                        for (Iterator<Entry<String, List<String>>> i = hKeys.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                                Entry<String, List<String>> m = i.next();

                                Log.w("HEADER_KEY", m.getKey() + "");
                                ret.headers.put(m.getKey(), m.getValue().toString());
                                if (m.getKey().equals("set-cookie"))
                                ret.cookies.put(m.getKey(), m.getValue().toString());
                        }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("HttpRequest", e.toString());
                }
                return ret;
        }
```

[image: con object while debug]

Comment: Why don't you give us the exception thrown?!

Comment: Did you add the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> tag to your manifest?

Comment: You mean to pull out the data from Exception e object? it will be enough,The thrown object e contain "detailMessage = Permission denied"

Comment: Jems you was right, i should add the permission to manifest file, Thanks a lot, but now each URL i am using is unresolved, the new exception :"Host is unresolved: www.google.com:80", when change the host name to IP it is working, DNS problem does anybody know how to fix?.

Comment: @Jems please add your comment as an answer so that @kimo can accept it as an accepted answer.

Comment: @kimo **Jems** hasn't seen your reply. It's described  [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) how notifications work for comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` tag to manifest
will fix the problem.
Thanks to Jems comment.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you get `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` and not `<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`! That bit me for an hour...