# BufferedReader is null in Android but not in Java when attempting to connect to internet

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, bufferedreader

I have a program which I originally created just in Java, and I am now attempting to format it as an app for Android. The program works just as I want it to in the Java console, but not when I run it as an Android Application.

This is the relevant code for my activity class:

```
public class ViewTeamStatsActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_team_stats);


    ArrayList<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();

    //Want to make sure there is a network available.  
    //This always returns true since I added the relevant permissions in the manifest
    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
    Main m = new Main();
    teams = m.download();
    }
```

So it calls my Main class which eventually calls the Retrieve class.  This class is then supposed to retrieve the HTML from a specific url and parse the content into usable data and return it as an ArrayList.

```
//Retrieves the HTML from the specified URL and then parses it into usable data.
public ArrayList<Game> Retrieve(String url)  {
    this.url = url;
    ArrayList<Game> data = new ArrayList<Game>();
    try {
        URL my_url = new URL(url);
        URLConnection conn = my_url.openConnection();

        //The following returns null when run "as an Android Application" but not in the Java console.  Why?
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        sort.addBufferedReader(br);
        data = sort.sort();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
}
```

So I guess my question is, why is the BufferedReader 'br' null if the program is being run on Android?  What is my code missing?

Note:  I've already added the relevant permissions so that is not the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

### In your case open connection returns null so first check if you have permission for Internet:

### uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/

Comment: Ihave solved this problem like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837050/con-getinputstream-throw-exception-in-android-project-how-to-fix  I'm sorry :(

Comment: The solution to that problem you linked to requires the person adding the permission in the manifest.  I have already done that so that must not be the solution.